# Kivymd : When combined, touch, scroll and swipe events can be messy

Tags: events, scroll, kivy, swipe, kivymd

I'm using kivy 2.2.0 and kivymd 1.1.1

I wrote a python script to have 3 swipes screens where in each screen there is a scrollview with HeroTiles.

The script works but it get messy when I swipe, sometimes, it swipes and click on the hero tile,
Or sometimes when I scroll, it click on the heroTile depending on how "good is my swipe". What would you recommend to make the events touch, scroll and swipe less messy: Here is the minimal code :

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty,ObjectProperty,NumericProperty, ListProperty
from kivymd.uix.hero import MDHeroFrom
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.swiper import MDSwiper
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton

titles1 = ["pizza","pasta","sandwich","french omelette","lasagna","tiramisu"]
titles2 = ["onion soup","beef bourguignon","caesar salad","crêpes","soufflé","ratatouille"]
titles3 = ["carot","onion","salad","col","butternut","cream"]

description_screenB = ["description1","description2","description3","description4","description5","description6"]

KV = '''

<MDHeroTo>:
  size_hint: 1, None
  height: "220dp"
  pos_hint: {"top": 1}

<MDSwiperItem>:
  MDScrollView:
    MDGridLayout:
      cols: 2
      spacing: "12dp"
      padding: "12dp"
      adaptive_height: True

<HeroItem>:
  size_hint_y: None
  height: "200dp"
  radius: 24

  MDSmartTile:
    id: tile
    on_release: 
      root.on_release()
    
    MDLabel:
      text: root.text

MyMDScreenManager:
  id: sm

  MyMDScreen:
    id: screenA
    name: "screen A"

    MyMDSwiper:
      id: _swiper
      width_mult: 0
      items_spacing: 0 

      MDSwiperItem:
        id: sw1 
        index: 1

      MDSwiperItem:
        id: sw2 
        index: 2

      MDSwiperItem:
        id: sw3
        index: 3




  MyMDScreen:
    id: screenB
    name: "screen B"
    heroes: [hero_to, hero_to_2, hero_to_3]
    hero_to: self.heroes[root.ids._swiper.index -1]

    MDBoxLayout:
      orientation: "vertical"

      MDHeroTo:
        id: hero_to

      MDHeroTo:
        id: hero_to_2

      MDHeroTo:
        id: hero_to_3

      MDScrollView:
        MDList:
          padding: "24dp", 0, "24dp", 0

          MDLabel:
            text: "Instructions"
            font_style: "H5"
            bold: True
            adaptive_height: True
            padding_y: "24dp"
          
          MDLabel:
            id: lbl
            adaptive_height: True
            text: root.ids.screenB.description

      MyMDIconButton:
        icon: "close"
        md_bg_color: 1, 1, 1, .6
        x: 12
        pos_hint: {"top": .99}
'''

class MyMDIconButton(MDIconButton):
  def on_release(self):
    Root = MDApp.get_running_app().root
    index = Root.ids._swiper.index -1
    Root.current_heroes = [Root.ids.screenB.heroes[index].tag]
    Root.current = "screen A"

class MyMDSwiper(MDSwiper):
  index = NumericProperty(1)
  
  def on_swipe_right(self):
    self.index = self.get_current_item().index

  def on_swipe_left(self):
    self.index = self.get_current_item().index


class MyMDScreen(MDScreen):
  description = StringProperty()
  heroes = ListProperty()

class HeroItem(MDHeroFrom):
  text = StringProperty()
  manager = ObjectProperty()
  source = StringProperty()
  description= StringProperty()

  def on_release(self):
    def switch_screen(*args):
      index = self.manager.ids._swiper.index -1

      self.manager.current_heroes = [self.tag]
      self.manager.ids.screenB.heroes[index].tag = self.tag       
      self.manager.current = "screen B"
      self.manager.screens[1].description = self.description

    Clock.schedule_once(switch_screen, 0.2)


class MyMDScreenManager(MDScreenManager):
  def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):

    for i in range(len(titles1)):
      instruction = description_screenB[i]

      hero_item1=HeroItem(
        text= titles1[i], tag = titles1[i] + "hero1", manager = self, description = instruction)
      
      hero_item2=HeroItem(
        text= titles2[i], tag = titles2[i] + "hero2", manager = self, description = instruction)

      hero_item3=HeroItem(
        text= titles3[i], tag = titles3[i] + "hero3", manager = self, description = instruction)

      self.ids.sw1.children[0].children[0].add_widget(hero_item1)
      self.ids.sw2.children[0].children[0].add_widget(hero_item2)
      self.ids.sw3.children[0].children[0].add_widget(hero_item3)


class MyTileApp(MDApp):
  def build(self):
    # self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
    return Builder.load_string(KV)

MyTileApp().run()
```

Thanks